# Cannot start Postgres because no space

Tags: centos

There is a VMware machine at work running CentOS 6.7. It uses Postgres 9.2. All I wanted is to start postgres service. This is probably related to it but I don't know what to do: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2111236. Note that I don't know what people did to it back in the time.

```
service postgresql-9.2 start
```

It keeps failing. I found where the logs were located at `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/pgstartup.log`.

Message:

```
FATAL:  could not write lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No space left on device
```

Disk free information:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        52G   51G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda3        40G  6.3G   31G  17% /var
```

The problem is obviously related to the lack of space but how do I solve it? Where is postgressql data located at?

Comment: First you defintely should solve the underlying problem - no space left on `/`.

Comment: Your postgres data can be found in /var/lib/pgsql.

Comment: @gunbert that's a bug in the VM. I can't solve it.

Comment: @SYN, thanks, I more likely wanted to know about dumping the database into a .bak file.

Comment: I still don't understand the reason for the downvote, but however I found a workaround. It might help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot fix /dev/sda1's space because it's VMware bug, I succeeded in changing the /tmp folder for the lock file.

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/postgresql.conf
```

For anyone having same issue, open the file above and add the following line in the end:

```
unix_socket_directory = '/dev/shm'
```

Note that I selected a folder with enough free space

```
df -h

tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
```